# Running a test that uses geolocator

Tags: flutter, testing, emulation

I'm trying to get a test that uses the geolocator plugin to run and pass from the Android Studio UI. If I run `flutter run path/to/test` and ensure it is either running on a connected device or an emulator, the test passes. If I run it with `flutter test` or right click on the file and either select "run tests in ..." or "run test_file.dart," a MissingPluginException will be thrown.

The class I'm testing:

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import '../model/constants/SearchOptionConstants.dart';
import '../model/utilities/GeolocatorWrapper.dart';

class LocationPresenter {

  late Position userCoordinates;
  String zipCodeFromLocation = SearchOptionConstants.defaultZipCode;
  bool hasPermission = false;
  late List<Placemark> userLocation;
  late Placemark userAddress;
  final GeolocatorWrapper _wrapper;

  LocationPresenter(this._wrapper);

  Future<void> setZipCodeFromLocation() async {
    await getPermission();
    if (hasPermission) {
      await getCoordinates();
      zipCodeFromLocation = userAddress.postalCode!;
    } else {
      zipCodeFromLocation = SearchOptionConstants.defaultZipCode;
    }
  }

  String getZipCodeFromLocation() {
    return zipCodeFromLocation;
  }

  Future<void> getPermission() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    if (await isLocationServiceEnabled()) {
      permission = await _wrapper.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        hasPermission = false;
        permission = await _wrapper.checkPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
          hasPermission = false;
        } else if (permission == LocationPermission.always || permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
          hasPermission = true;
        }
      } else if (permission == LocationPermission.always || permission == LocationPermission.whileInUse) {
        hasPermission = true;
      }
    } else {
      hasPermission = false;
    }
  }

  Future<Placemark> getCoordinates() async {
    userCoordinates = await _wrapper.getCurrentPosition();
    List<Placemark> userPlacemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(userCoordinates.latitude, userCoordinates.longitude);
    userAddress = userPlacemark[0];
    return userAddress;
  }

  Future<bool> isLocationServiceEnabled() async {
    return await _wrapper.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  }

}
```

The test file:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:part_scavenger/model/utilities/GeolocatorWrapper.dart';
import 'package:part_scavenger/presenter/LocationPresenter.dart';
import 'LocationPresenter_test.mocks.dart';

@GenerateMocks([GeolocatorWrapper])

void main() {

  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('LocationPresenter', () {
    test('setZipCodeFromLocation properly uses location zip code if permission is always granted', () async {
      final LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper);

      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.isLocationServiceEnabled()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(true));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.requestPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.always));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570})));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "37620");
    });

    test('setZipCodeFromLocation properly uses location zip code if permission is while ine use', () async {
      final LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper);

      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.isLocationServiceEnabled()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(true));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.requestPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.whileInUse));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570})));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "37620");
    });

    test('denied forever permission uses default zip code', () async {
      final LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper);

      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.isLocationServiceEnabled()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(true));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.requestPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.deniedForever));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.checkPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.deniedForever));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570})));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "Zip Code");
    });

    test('if location service is disabled, default zip code is used', () async {
      final LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = LocationMockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper);

      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.isLocationServiceEnabled()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(false));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.requestPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.deniedForever));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.checkPermission()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(LocationPermission.deniedForever));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570})));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "Zip Code");
    });

  });  // end of group*/

}
```

What causes the `MissingPluginException` when running with flutter test or through the Android Studio UI, and how can I get this to work properly and run successfully with all of my other tests by right-clicking and selecting "run tests in ..." From the UI?